# How to make a column in a Postgres table with limited selection

Tags: sql, postgresql, check-constraints

Noob to SQL here. Is there any way to constrain (not in terms of primary/foreign key) the selection of a column?  Specifically, I want to a table called “occupation” with only two options, either clown or doctor.

Comment: `select * from occupation where column_option in (clown, doctor)`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods.  The simplest is a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t
    add constraint chk_t_occupation
        check (occupation in ('clown', 'doctor'));
```

The second method is to have an `occupations` table with two rows.  You can then have an `occupationId` column with a foreign key reference to this table.